# How to make a bootable CD of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04

I wan to take a laptop with DOS only. I want a Ubuntu 12.04 Boot-Able CD do that I can boot my system at any time whenever needed. How can I make a boot-able CD? Can you please tell me the complete procedure for that?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to know how to make a CD with the Ubuntu installer on it? Or how to make a bootable CD that is a clone of an existing installed system?

Comment: In windows, http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows. In linux, http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu

Comment: @bain No. I want to make a bootable Ubuntu CD so that whenever I would put this CD in system, it will install a new Ubuntu OS in my system. I hope I am clear now.

Comment: @NehalJ.Wani but how will you make it if you don't have any OS in your PC? The dealer will give me only DOS which doesn't have any Ubuntu and Windows. So, how will you make it then? Use someone else PC?

Comment: @hellodear2 Isn't that obvious? I don't think you can burn disks in DOS or browse the internet.

Comment: Actually, Where can I get the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS ISO file so that I can download and make a bootable CD? I am getting link of the latest version of it on official site. Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to perfectly solve your question. Regardless of your current operating system.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto

I recommend using a USB stick to install ubuntu :D its.. er... reusable :D

**YOU WILL NEED TO SET USB TO FIRST BOOT IN YOUR BIOS**

> > I dont like doing this step, so what I do is during boot mash the F# keys, one of them lets you select which drive to boot from, in your case you would select the USB stick. Obviously mashing the F# keys is a bad strat but it did help me find the correct F# key. in my case its F7.

Unetbootin is a program that will let you install a ubuntu .iso from a usb stick you can download it at: http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Yumi lets you use the USB stick to install ubuntu plus also use the left over space for storage. Yumi also lets you store multiple linux distros on the same USB stick. download it at: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/

Here is the official documentation for installing ubuntu onto a USB

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

.

.

.

many programs let you add "persistence" to the USB stick, which means that every time you boot using the USB stick all your changes are saved! if you read the official documentation for USB installs you'll come accross Unetbootin which is what I use when I want to add persistence.

Comment: Should I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS or the latest version of it? I am asking because I have heard that there are lot of problems in the latest version. Can you elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: I have had no problems installing any version of ubuntu. I really recommend you download Unetbootin and download whatever ubuntu .iso you want.

I used this method to install 10.04, 12.04, 13.04, and 14.04. Read the official documentation link. scroll down to the portion about Unetbootin.

If you search engine a bit with the keywords "ubuntu" "usb" "install" youll have all your questions solved.

Comment: Try reading through this link 

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

Unetbootin ----->(DOWNLOAD AT: http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/ ) WORKS FOR ALL OPERATING SYSTEMS